# Need to .htaccess redirect path with a variable URI segmant to another directory without changing URL

Tags: .htaccess

My current .htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^[0-9]+/pos  /pos/$1 [L]
```

Currently this will redirect a url such as **example.com/234234234/pos** to **example.com/pos**

I would like it to load the directory **example.com/pos**, but without losing the original URL (**example.com/234234234/pos**) from the address bar.

Basically, the number listed in the url can change, but I always want it to load the same path.

Comment: So what's wrong with your rules?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The URL gets changed when it re-routes. I would like it not to.

Answer (score 1):

This rule doesn't look right:

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]+/pos  /pos/$1 [L]
```

As you're not capturing anything hence there is no `$1`. If you want to ignore any number before `/pos` then use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]+/(pos)/?$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you. Functionally speaking it still does the same thing, however, I figure this is going to keep problems from happening later.. Still redirects, though.

Comment: Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: 1) yes, this is the only .htaccess 2) yes, everything posted is the only code in it. 2) root of the site.

Comment: Ok got it. Above rule doesn't redirect since there is no `R` flag. Do you have any CMS/PHP framework running?

Comment: Even your rule `RewriteRule ^[0-9]+/pos/ /pos/ [L,NC]` wouldn't change URL in browser. If URL is changing then it is because of some other rule OR inside the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you anubhava. Part of your answer helped me. I did want the numbers ignored, but didn't want them to disappear.

This is the line I needed: 
    RewriteRule ^[0-9]+/pos/ /pos/ [L,NC]

Did not need to capture anything at all. That is what was causing the redirect.